# Partition By Variable not accessible in where clause

Tags: sql-server, dense-rank, partition-by

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cs.file_id,  
    null, 
    'lol', 
    t.encounter_id, 
    e.pan, e.mr, 
    e.provider_id, 
    t.c_date_of_service, 
    GETDATE(),
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC) row
FROM 
    encounters e WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN 
    dummy ec ON ec.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
JOIN 
    case_status cs ON cs.case_id = ec.case_id
JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
         e.encounter_id, c.date_of_service AS c_date_of_service
     FROM 
         encounters e WITH (NOLOCK)
     JOIN 
         dummy ec ON ec.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
     JOIN 
         cases c ON ec.case_id = c.case_id
     GROUP BY
         e.pid, c.date_of_service, e.encounter_id
     HAVING
         (COUNT(0) > 1 AND e.pid IS NOT NULL)) AS t ON t.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
WHERE
    row = 1
```

I'm getting an error

> Invalid column name 'row'

If I just remove `where row = 1` it works fine in SQL Server.

One more thing - `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC)` shows different row numbers, `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC)` shows all rank as 1 where there is duplicate `encounter_id` in the resulting data.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC)` shows different row number, `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC)` shows all rank as 1 where there is duplicate encounter_id  in the resulting data.

Comment: Look for mismatched parentheses

Comment: You cannot use "computed" column in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement that creates it. You need to use a subquery as follows: `SELECT * FROM ([your entire query minus where clause]) AS a WHERE row = 1`

Comment: doesn't work in msserver.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use a computed column in where clause directly, you need to wrap it inside an inline query, and then add where clause on it .

```
select * from (SELECT DISTINCT
        cs.file_id,  
        null, 
        'lol', 
        t.encounter_id, 
        e.pan, e.mr, 
        e.provider_id, 
        t.c_date_of_service, 
        GETDATE(),
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.encounter_id ORDER BY e.encounter_id DESC) row
    FROM 
        encounters e WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN 
        dummy ec ON ec.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
    JOIN 
        case_status cs ON cs.case_id = ec.case_id
    JOIN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT
             e.encounter_id, c.date_of_service AS c_date_of_service
         FROM 
             encounters e WITH (NOLOCK)
         JOIN 
             dummy ec ON ec.encounter_id = e.encounter_id
         JOIN 
             cases c ON ec.case_id = c.case_id
         GROUP BY
             e.pid, c.date_of_service, e.encounter_id
         HAVING
                 (COUNT(0) > 1 AND e.pid IS NOT NULL)) AS t ON t.encounter_id = 
                          e.encounter_id

        ) as A WHERE A.row = 1
```